# How to detect incoming network transfers in windows (preferably in c#)

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-8

I was wondering if anyone knows how (or even if it is possible) to monitor and trigger an action when a computer running windows (7-8) starts reciving a file transfer from over the network onto one of its drives.

Bonus points if I can find out how big the file is that the other guy is placing on my machine and how much is done etc...

I want to know if there is any API in windows, or snippit of code, or some other API that provides any of this functionality.

I still want to be able to recive files, I just want to manage them better. I am on a network with over 90 computers and this software that I wish to write would be running on most of them.

Comment: What you're asking is very broad. Yes, such a program is probably very possible but stackoverflow is a place for specific questions.

Comment: Disable folder sharing. No one can put the file remotely on your computer, it can be placed into a shared folder only.

Comment: Sorry this is my first question on here before.


I want to know if there is any API in windows, or snippit of code, or some other API that provides any of this functionality.


-Karel Frajtak
I very much want to be able to recive files, if I couldn't recive files what would be the point of this question? I am on a network with over 90 computers and this software that I wish to write would be running on most of them.


@gideon
I'm sorry I thought I was specific. Sorry, do you know of an API or windows call that can let me get closer to writing this program?

Comment: Maybe you ought to consider a filesystemwatcher?

Comment: @Mr47 I thought they couldn't be used system wide (only for 1 folder at a time etc...) and I wouldn't be able to get the remaining length of the data to be sent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can (after all it's what an Antivirus program does) but it's NOT easy and probably you'll see it's more comfortable to do in C than in C#. I'm sure there's a .NET porting of WinPCap anyway you can always P/Invoke.

Start reading about [Network Monitor SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee847219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. It's not an easy task, you have to capture a specific set of frames, you may use a Network Packet Monitor to inspect the content and the type of the packets you have to capture and parse.

I'm not sure but you may take a look to [QoS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (start reading [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742487.aspx)), it should provide something you can use.

Comment: Thanks this is a great start.

Comment: Using packet capture for this is way overkill. Why not go to the file system driver, maybe with a filter driver.

Comment: @Deanna Because he can't **know the full file size** of the file to download before it's completed. I guess if he can accept _something_ less he can write _a lot_ less code.

Comment: @Adriano: How will packet capture help? Unless the copier sets the file size first, it won't be in the traffic, and if it is, then the size will be passed to the file system.

Comment: @Deanna File size will be provided in the header (so the browser, ftp client or whatever they use) can estimate required time but _usually_ they do no pre-allocate the required space on the file system.

Comment: I was under the impression the OP was asking about SMB/standard networking access to that machine as the server, NOT as a client downloading it via HTTP or FTP

Comment: @Deanna It's not really clear if he want to monitor that on the server or the client...

Comment: @Deanna Sorry everyone for not being specific enough, to clarify I want a

Comment: @Deanna Sorry everyone for not being specific enough, to clarify I want to have a small program running on my machine (and many others) that detects an incoming file transfer that is being transferred via the windows filesystem and over local network. So if I send someone a file over the network to there desktop (say a new test build that I want them to run) the program (running on their machine) would notify them that I was transferring them a file and when it is complete, reducing the need for me to tell them when I am transferring something and when its done etc...

Comment: Can't you do it from your machine with a batch and a _net send_ message? :)

Comment: This sounds like the easiest way is to poll a specific folder (on the netowrk or local) and prompt them if there is a new setup available.

Comment: @Deanna he needs to know the progrss of the operation. Maybe there is something interesting here (but I didn't check if it works in network too): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144063(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Adriano I think that the copy hook could work. I can just make the software run on all machines and when comp A sends a file to comp B it can notify the service on comp B that it is getting a file send to it along with the size etc... That is assuming that this works on network transfers. I could just monitor a folder but would rather have any network transfers to any part of any drive monitored which rules out a file watcher I think.

Comment: @Adriano Its not just for sending o e type of file to one computer we must send 20 or so files per person per day to each other or a fileserver and i would like to log each one, and also notify recepients of the transfer ( currently we intercom or email someone when we send them a file...) a popup on the bottom right is my end goal with the filesize, name, time remaining and maybe a cancel for the receiver.